# Setting up RBAC plugin in Jenkins to provide user access to pipelines starting with specific keywords

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, rbac

I have a jenkins setup and installed in an ec2 instance, with RBAC plugin installed. I need to have a few set of pipelines there. Now, I need a particular set of users have access to pipelines whose name start with "Salesforce-.*" and another set of users to have access to pipelines starting with "Ingeniator-.*". how can I do it?

I tried giving following permissions for global roles[image], and following permission for Item roles, so that the user will only be able to view pipelines starting with Ingeniator. [image]. Then I added one user for global and Item role. but I can see both the pipeline when I am logging in via that user.